# In policy gradient algorithms, if the model always predicts any action with a probability of 1, will the gradient always be 0?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients

The loss of policy gradient:

$$
\nabla_{\theta}J(\theta)=\mathbb{E}_{\tau\sim\pi\theta}\left[\sum_{t=0}^{T}(R_t-b_t)\nabla_{\theta}\log\pi_\theta(a_t|s_t)\right]
$$

where $\pi_\theta(a_t|s_t)$ is the probability of the model $\theta$ predicting the action $a_t$ in the state $s_t$.

Howerver, if the model always predicts a certain incorrect action with a probability of 1, then it necessarily follows that $\log\pi_\theta(a_t|s_t)=0$. So the loss is alwasy 0.

I discovered this issue because I found that my model always overfits by outputting any action with a probability of 1, and there's a high chance it's an incorrect action. At this point, the loss is 0, and convergence stops. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"So the loss is always 0"* doesn't mean that there is no learning... indeed, it's called "policy gradient", not "policy loss", thus you have to consider the gradient of the logarithm evaluated at 1 (since $\pi(a|s) = 1)$)

And indeed, $\nabla \ln \pi(a|s)$ when $\pi(a|s) = 1$ is $1$, thus learning can definitely still happen (though it might be slow)